# How to put an image next to each other in mailchimp

Tags: html, mailchimp

Someone, can help me out? I'm searching for a code so 2 images will show up next to each other in Mobile. With the standard Mailchimp templates it isn't possible (i guess).

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help in your code.**  Before posting future questions please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stack Overflow and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a question with [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and simple example of how this can be done. You can use this code in MailChimp and it should work. Add in a single column block, view the code and add this in. Change the image source and you should be good to go.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; max-width: 600px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%"><img src="http://www.mybligr.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/most-beautiful-tiger-animals-pics-images-photos-pictures-7-300x300.jpg" style="display: block;width:100%; max-width: 300px; height: auto;" /></td>
      <td width="50%"><img src="http://www.mybligr.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/most-beautiful-tiger-animals-pics-images-photos-pictures-7-300x300.jpg" style="display: block;width:100%; max-width: 300px; height: auto;" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! 
But Mailchimp say's:

Useful Classes:
mcnTextContent - Add to any container (e.g. <div>, <span>, or <td>) to inherit all text styles you've set in the Design tab.
mcnImage - Add to <img> tags to get rid of the space below images and make them fluid in mobile email clients that support media queries. 

so is it possible that you still can use the upload and the CSS in Mailchimp? Or do i need to add it by myself?

Comment: If u are coding your own then use the above. Alternatively you can use the two columns block they have I guess but I don't like it when I am not in control of the email I build.

Comment: Well i'm not that good at it, so when i place it this: <td mcnTextContent width="100%"> it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using their content blocks? Or coded your own?

Comment: Using my own. It isn't possible with the content blocks of Mailchimp

Comment: I wouldn't use their classes. Just use your own code.

Comment: Does this answer work? If correct you can choose it as correct answer.